# ExpertPdf - Could not get conversion result header. Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 109

Tags: pdf, pdf-conversion

I am using **ExpertPdf** **HtmlToPdf** library. When I try to **AddElement** to **PdfPage** I get an exception: 
"**Could not get conversion result header. Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 109**". I have no idea why is that.

Code below:

```
PdfPage page = doc.Pages.AddNewPage();

HtmlToPdfElement htmlToPdfElement = new HtmlToPdfElement(0,0,0-1,"cos",null);

AddElementResult result = page.AddElement(htmlToPdfElement);
```

Comment: Did you include the *.dat file in your build output? Next to the *.dll? If not, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460500/evopdf-library-fails-on-windows-azure-hosted-site/43844040#43844040 for more info.

Comment: Is there any solution? i have same issue

Answer (score 2):

If you change application pool identity to user which has admin rights, it solves the problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why? This sometimes works for me and sometimes does not. Is this the same behaviour you saw?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the ExpertPdf is, however the error is similar to what is described in troubleshooting guide for [EVO HTML to PDF Converter](https://www.evopdf.com/help/html_to_pdf/html/927b8d41-62ae-4ad6-a51a-368829d247f5.htm):

> **The conversion fails with 'Data receive error. Could not receive data. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown', 'Memory allocation error. Try the 64-bit version', 'Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 6', 'Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 0', 'Data receive error. Could not receive data. Error code: 109' error messages or you see the 'Exception code: 0xc0000005' in Windows logs for evointernal.dat process**
>
> These error messages can indicate a memory allocation error in converter. In general you can avoid memory allocation issues by running the converter in a 64-bit environment. This is the recommended configuration for EVO HTML to PDF Converter. When you run the converter in ASP.NET you have to set the 'Enable 32-bit' flag of the IIS application pool on false to make sure the converter runs in a 64-bit process. It is also recommended to use the version of the converter optimized for 64-bit environments, which is provided as a separate download on our website. This version should also avoid the memory allocation issues that might occur during the navigation.

Looks like they use the same engine. Hope this helps.